# Does a single photon diffract when fired at a single slit?

Tags: double-slit-experiment, diffraction

A beam of light fired at a single aperture produces a diffraction pattern on the screen.

A beam of light fired at a double slit produces an interference pattern.

Individual photons fired at a double slit also produce an interference pattern, by building up discrete dots on the screen.

If individual photons are fired at an aperture, do we see the same thing?  i.e, a diffraction pattern built up from discrete dots?

This seems like a trivial question but I can't seem to find any information on it.  Any answers or sources are very much appreciated.  Cheers!

Comment: Yes, it builds up in the same way. There is no difference in the physics between the various cases, so there is no need of lots of material to cover it.

Comment: Re, "...seems like a trivial question..." Well, think about it. You accept that the behavior of a beam of light is just the sum of the behaviors of its individual photons when there are two slits, but then you question whether covering up one of the slits would break that rule. Your question makes it feel like you're looking for a more complicated model of how nature works—kind of the opposite of what most physicists strive to do.

Comment: Yes, also note that an "interference" pattern is also present for light on a single aperture.  The pattern has much lower fringe density.

Comment: Photons diffract around edges or scatter off edges. A single slit has two edges. From those two points you can calculate the minimum‘s where opposed phasing will cancel at the screen. Note you will even get a pattern with a single edge.

Comment: see this single slit pattern https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~cass/courses/m309-03a/m309-projects/krzak/ . Nobody seems to have bothered to repeat the single slit with single photons , one expects that the mathematics works .

Comment: Thanks everyone!  I'm surprised that nobody has bothered to test this - even if simply for completeness.  It seems a mistake to infer a result when we have no complete theory.  To those who have answered 'yes', are you referring to a specific experiment?